# ¿Cómo capturar la salida estándar/error al invocar un proceso?

Tags: c#

Tengo el llamado a un proceso de linea de comandos de la siguiente forma:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.FileName = processname;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;

p.Start();
p.WaitForExit()
```

Me gustaría "capturar" la salida estándar o la de error, en principio no las necesito, solo quiero que la ejecución del proceso sea lo más "silenciosa" posible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando se instancia un objeto de la clase [`Process()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8), debemos configurar  [`StartInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_StartInfo), dentro de ésta tenemos las propiedades:

- `RedirectStandardOutput`
- `RedirectStandardError`

Que permiten hacer lo siguiente:

```
public static void execute(string processname, string arguments) {
   Process p = new Process();
   p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
   p.StartInfo.FileName = processname;
   p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
   p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
   p.Start();
   p.WaitForExit();

   var stdout = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
   var stderr = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Ahora si, usando [`StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_StandardOutput) y [`StandardError.ReadToEnd()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_StandardError) podemos leer la salida y el error estándar y asignarlas a sendas variables. Prestar atención también a las propiedades `StandardErrorEncoding` y `StandardOutputEncoding`.